# Error from gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc

What does the following error mean:

```
In function `get_ints`:
`l` undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Larger code sample will help to disambiguate the question.

Comment: misspelled/undeclared variable l?

Comment: Posting more code will be helpful.

Comment: in ehich line is i showing the error? post that line.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler complains about variable `l` being undeclared. Just from experience - check your integer constants, there's a chance you have `l` instead of `1` somewhere there.

Answer (score 1):

You used `l` somewhere and didn't define it.